# Datanode not starting in Hadoop / ubuntu

Tags: server, ssh

I tried to start datanode in Hadoop - the result below showed that:

```
util.NativeCodeLoder: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform...
```

`$ start-all.sh`

```
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
17/02/04 17:18:19 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/hadoop1/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop1-namenode-ubuntu.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/hadoop1/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop1-datanode-ubuntu.out
Start**ing secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/hadoop1/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop1-secondarynamenode-ubuntu.out
17/02/04 17:18:36 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /home/hadoop1/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop1-resourcemanager-ubuntu.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /home/hadoop1/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop1-nodemanager-ubuntu.out
```

Here is the result below:

```
jps
10034 NameNode
10661 NodeManager
10373 SecondaryNameNode
10533 ResourceManager
10956 Jps****
```